# Get width and height of ImageView on orientation change

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I'm trying to fit a bitmap into an ImageView that changes size when rotating the device.
It changes size because I load different layouts for portrait and landscape mode respectively.
I calculate the final bitmap size based on how much available screen space the ImageView has when it has been placed on the layout.

At the moment I'm trying to solve this by taking care of the configuration change (rotation) myself.

I have tried using onConfigurationChanged and ViewTreeObserver with some success. As long as I do not use setContentView I get width and height of the ImageView and the scaling is done accordingly. However, I need to be able to load another layout and based on the ImageView's available space, calculate a new scaling for the bitmap.

How do I accomplish this? As soon as I load a new layout, the width and height of the ImageView become zero.

My goal is to have the bitmap size scaled to fit the imageview on rotation.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also notice the `ImageView` goes to 0 when I do a configuration change. But I can't scale a `Bitmap` with a 0 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of methods you can override including onSizeChanged and onLayout, but all of them have quirks. The most reliable way I've found to find out a views size is to use a view tree observer. The width and height you get from the view in the observer can change, and is often 0 the first or first several times onGlobalLayout is changed.

Try just logging the width and height of your desired view in onGlobalLayout in a view tree observer and see what happens. Also be sure that after you call setContentView, you call findViewById again to find whatever ImageView object takes the place of the old one. If you're still looking at the image view before the rotation, the width and height will never be accurate since that view is no longer in any visible layout.

Comment: It seems there is no golden solution to his and for now I've thrown out the ViewTreeObserver and instead pass data between saved instance states. This means I have to resample the incoming bitmap so I don't hit the VM budget limit but if nothing else, it works.
Your reply did however have some important pointers, so I will accept your answer.

Comment: @shellströmSONY, did the saving state work? I tried to but got a new error: `requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView`. Which means while I'm trying to access my view to save it, Android is trying to also use my view, so there's a conflict. Haven't found a way around it though, as `ViewTreeObserver` didn't work for me either.